# linux terminal output redundant content

Tags: c, arch

My Linux is Arch, my configuration is as follows:

```
Kernel: 5.13.13-arch1-1
Packages: 490 (pacman)
Shell: zsh 5.8
WM: dwm
Terminal: st
Terminal Font: Source Code Pro
```

When I use C output statements, such as `printf` and `putchar('A');`, if I don't add \r or \n at the end, I will get an extra '%' character on the terminal.

```
$ ./a.out
A%
$
```

This problem has troubled me for a long time, so that I don't know who is the problem, with dwm? With sh? With zhs?

Comment: don't paste code/text as images

Comment: If you add `'\n'` at the end the issue goes away? It's good to add `'\n'` at the end. Many *utilities* interpret line as "bunch of chars terminated by **and including** a newline"

Comment: Why is there a `c` in front of `./a.out`?

Comment: Try `$ ./a.out | hd -c`

Comment: Please add plain text as (formatted) text directly into your question instead of pictures of consoles showing plain text.

Comment: The first time I use stack overflow, I am very sorry, the previous C is my current folder name, and the output of ./a.out |od is:0000000  000101 0000001   ,I don't know how to add pictures in this, I'm very sorry

Comment: That od output means `1` byte from `./a.out` with the octal value `000101` which is `A` (`65`), so the extra character is not from your executable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your criticisms and corrections. The solution I have found, as described in the answer, I only need to modify it in .zsh

Comment: @tstanisl: In this case, the image of terminal window text is relevant and appropriate, as the coloring and altered background convey information about the source or nature of the various text, and the question goes to the display of text, rather than its content *per se*. For example, the black-on-white of the `%` contrasted with the white-on-black `A` is a clue that the `%` was not output by the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature of zsh to show when a program has ended without a final newline and to distinguish zsh’s command prompt from the program output.

[You can disable it with the zsh command `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167582/why-zsh-ends-a-line-with-a-highlighted-percent-symbol) You can also set it to something else, such as `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=' -- The program did not end with a newline.'`.

Comment: thank  you very much,very very very very very very much